# JQuery onmouseover only affecting to one component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create an animation for all the divs called switch in the html. Imagine for example the typical iphone Cocoa switch. The animation works Ok, But it's only applied to the first component not for all of them, although they are all called switch

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using the `id` "switch", or a `class` called "switch"?  IDs *must* be unique, you typically want to use a class if you want multiple of something with the same behavior.

Comment: Might it be they all have an `id` of "switch"? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Ok, I have all id instead of class. I just changed it, together with the style ( dot-notation ). The problem now is affecting to all components. $(".photoItemWhite").mouseover(function(){    
   $(".photoItemWhite").animate({
    top: "-25px"
   }, 500 );
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well change your handler:

```
$('.photoItemWhite').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({top: '-25px'}, 500);
});
```

When jQuery calls your event handler, it will make sure that `this` refers to the element for which the handler is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".photoItemWhite").mouseover(function(){ $(this).animate({ top: "-25px" }, 500 ); });
```

use **this** keyword